# String formatting. Get keyword parameter from local environment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I see the following pattern fairly often and would like to know if there's a way to avoid the duplication.

```
life = 42
badger = some_function()
s = "({life}, {badger})".format(life=life,badger=badger)
```

The local variables usually have coherent names that correspond to their meaning in the string. I'm currently using the more concise:

```
s = "({0}, {1})".format(life,badger)
```

The template is usually more legible using keywords. Is there a general / concise way to get format to look up the keywords in the lexical environment of the containing function?

```
s  = "({life}, {badger})".format(env())
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `locals()`.

```
s  = "({life}, {badger})".format(**locals())
```

Comment: `**locals()` is very good, thanks. Four good answers within two minutes is pretty amazing.

Comment: Remember that `locals()` provide you only with a dictionary of variables in the local scope - if you were to call this from a function none of the outer variables will be available. You actually need to create a new dict combining `globals()` and `locals()` in order to get the 'full scope': `.format(**dict(globals(), **locals()))` at which point it starts becoming clunky, memory inefficient and ridden with potential problems. I'd advise you to extend `string.Formatter` and implement your own scope handling and value-on-request calls instead.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.6 already addresses this with [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/); f-strings:

```
>>> life = '2'
>>> badger = 'more'
>>> f'{life} {badger}'
'2 more'
```

If upgrading isn't going to cost so much, then you can look in this direction.

Comment: That's interesting. f-strings are exactly what I was hoping for. 3.6 is a stretch though, 2.7 is a much easier sell :(

Answer (score 1):

Moses' answer is awesome for python 3

If you need something for python 2 you can try this:

## Somehow come out with a dict

```
In [6]: env = dict(life=42, badger='badger')

In [7]: env
Out[7]: {'badger': 'badger', 'life': 42}

In [11]: "({life}, {badger})".format(**env)
Out[11]: '(42, badger)'

In [12]: "({0}, {1})".format(*env)
Out[12]: '(life, badger)'

In [13]:
```

Example with os.environ

```
In [13]: import os

In [14]: "({0}, {1})".format(*os.environ)
Out[14]: '(VIEWCLIENT_WINDOWS_TIMEZONE, VIEWCLIENT_BROKER_DOMAINNAME)'

In [15]:
```

Disclaimer: I read this early and before coffee.  While the technique works.  The other guys are correct that you can use locals in place of os.environ.

I was more focused on using the *'s

Comment: That's very interesting. I shall see whether the local bindings are available at runtime - I'm optimistic that they will be

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use f-strings, there is the option of using [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) together with the `**kwargs` argument passing form:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 5
>>> '{a} {b}'.format(**locals())
'3 5'
```